# Shiny Azure WebApp Authenticate as user to Azure SQL Server

Tags: r, sql-server, azure, shiny

I'm building a WebApp with a SQL DB as Backend. I'm Deploying the both parts on Azure, as Azure Webapp and SQL Server.

The SQL server is sercured with Azure AD (AAD). So only Users in a Group can access the DB.

So I'm trying to setup a workflow where the Webapp login the user and collect his Access token. And then uses the token to Query the SQL server.

I've registreted the App in AAD, where it is authorized to read the user ID and impersonate as the user.

I've the following code which is working local. But I can't get it to work deployed locally in a Docker Image.

```
# app file
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinyjs)
library(AzureAuth)

db <- "Azure"
config <- config::get(config = db)

redirect <- 'http://localhost:1410/app/'

ui_func <- function(req) {
  useShinyjs()
  opts <- parseQueryString(req$QUERY_STRING)
  if( is.null(opts$code) ) {
    auth_uri <- build_authorization_uri(
                  resource = config$resource, 
                  tenant = config$tenant, 
                  app = config$app, 
                  redirect_uri = redirect, 
                  # version = 2, 
                  prompt = 'login')
    redir_js <- sprintf('location.replace(\"%s\");', auth_uri)
    tags$script(HTML(redir_js))
  } else {
    fluidPage(
        verbatimTextOutput('token1'), 
        verbatimTextOutput('token2'),
        verbatimTextOutput('token_list'),
        verbatimTextOutput('path'),
        tableOutput('files'),
        tableOutput("db_tables")
        )
  }
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  opts <- parseQueryString(isolate(session$clientData$url_search))
  if(is.null(opts$code))
    return()
  #get_azure_token(
  #            config$resource, 
  #            config$tenant, 
  #            config$app,
  #            #pssw,
  #            # version = 2,
  #            auth_type = 'authorization_code', 
  #            use_cache = FALSE, 
  #            auth_code = opts$code) -> 
  tok1 <- NULL
  get_azure_token(
                  config$resource2, 
                  config$tenant, 
                  config$app, 
                  password = config$secret, 
                  auth_type = 'authorization_code', 
                  use_cache = FALSE, 
                  # auth_type='on_behalf_of', 
                  # on_behalf_of = tok1,
                  auth_code = opts$code
                  ) -> 
  tok2
  output$token <- renderPrint(tok1)
  output$token2 <- renderPrint(tok2)
  renderText({
    rappdirs::user_data_dir() %>% 
      fs::dir_ls() }) -> 
  output$path
  renderText({
    list_azure_tokens() 
  }) ->
  output$token_list

  renderTable({
    rappdirs::user_data_dir() %>% 
      fs::path(., 'AzureR') %>%
      fs::dir_ls(., all = TRUE) %>% 
      tibble::as_tibble()
  }) ->
  output$files
  
  pool <- NULL
  if(!is.null(tok2)) {
    if(db == "Azure") {
      pool::dbPool(
            drv = odbc::odbc(), 
            Driver = config$driver, 
            Server = config$server, 
            Database = config$database, 
            Port = config$port,
            Encrypt = config$encrypt,
            TrustServerCertificate = config$trustservercertificate,
            ConnectionTimeout = config$connectiontimeout,
            Authentication = config$authentication
            ) -> 
      pool
    } 
    if(db == "PCI") {
      pool::dbPool(
            odbc::odbc(),
            drv = odbc::odbc(), 
            Driver = config$driver, 
            Server = config$server, 
            Database = config$database, 
            TrustedConnection = config$trustedconnection
            ) -> 
      pool
    }
  }
  onStop(function() {
           pool::poolClose(pool)})
  reactive({
    dat <- NULL
    if(!is.null(pool)) {
      pool %>% 
        DBI::dbListTables(.) %>% 
        dplyr::as_tibble() -> 
      dat}
    return(dat)
  }) -> 
  db_tables
  output$db_tables <- renderTable({
    db_tables()})
}
shinyApp(ui_func, server)
```

Dockerfile

```
# Dockerfile to test azure
ARG SHINY_PORT=1410
ARG SHINY_HOST="127.0.0.1"
ARG DOCKER_DEPLOY="local"
FROM rocker/shiny-verse:4.0.5
ARG SHINY_PORT
ARG SHINY_HOST
ARG DOCKER_DEPLOY 

RUN apt-get update -y \
  && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    gnupg

# See about installing ODBC drivers here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017
# Note that the driver version installed needs to match the version used in the code
# In this case for Ubuntu 18.04: ODBC SQL driver 17
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools
RUN apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev


RUN echo "\noptions(shiny.port=${SHINY_PORT}, shiny.host='${SHINY_HOST}')\n" >> /usr/local/lib/R/etc/Rprofile.site

## add any R 
RUN R -e 'install.packages(c("fs", "pkgload", "remotes", "tibble", "lubridate","shiny", "shinyjs", "shinythemes", "hms", "tidyverse", "magrittr", "AzureAuth"), dependencies = TRUE)'
RUN R -e 'install.packages(c("DT", "odbc", "rmarkdown","janitor", "reactable", "pool", "config","RODBC","DBI", "httpuv"), dependencies = TRUE )'

RUN mkdir /srv/shiny-server/app \
  && chown -R shiny:shiny /srv/shiny-server/app
COPY . /srv/shiny-server/app/

# setup shiny server. Create nessesarry dirs for server
COPY ./shiny-server.sh /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh
COPY ./shiny-server.conf /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf

EXPOSE 1410 

# start server. Use sh from rocker project
CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
```

```
# config file for app
default:
  resource: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/'
  # resource: 'https://management.azure.com' 
  # resource: 
  #   - 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
  #   - 'openid'
  #   - 'profile'
  #   - 'email'
  #   - 'offline_access'
  #   # - 'User.Read'
  resource2: 'https://database.windows.net/'
  tenant: 'xxxxxxx'
  app: 'xxxxxxx'
  secret: 'xxxxxxxxx'
  driver: 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'

PCI:
  inherits: default
  server: 'xxxxxx'
  # port: 'xxxxx'
  database: 'xxxxx'
  trustedconnection: 'xxxx'

Azure:
  inherits: default
  server: 'xxxxx'
  port: 'xxxxxx'
  database: 'xxxxxx'
  encrypt: 'yes'
  trustservercertificate: 'no'
  connectiontimeout: '30'
  # authentication: 'ActiveDirectoryPassword'
  authentication: 'ActiveDirectoryIntegrated'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connecting to SQL Server with an OAuth token requires use of a [pre-connection attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-azure-active-directory?view=sql-server-ver15#authenticating-with-an-access-token) (basically a pointer to the token string). There is an [open feature request](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/299) at the odbc Github repo for this. I encourage you to upvote it, hopefully if it's popular enough it will get implemented.

Comment: UPDATE: this feature has recently [been added to odbc](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/pull/521). I haven't managed to get it working yet, but I suspect it's now possible.